# ¿Como ordenar correctamente en mysql un alfanumerico separado por /?

Tags: php, mysql, orderby

Trabajo en PHP7 Y Mysql puro, no hay frameworks. Quiero realizar una consulta con un orden descendente, pero mi campo VARCHAR a veces tiene "2578" y en otras filas tiene "178/1999", por lógica el orden sale cualquier cosa, la idea es hacer dos consultas, una por el tipo numérico que en otro campo llamado "tipo" lo clasifico que es, por ejemplo "2578" es "identificador" y "178/1999" es "expediente", entonces los largo por separado, primero consulto los identificadores y hasta ahí todo bien del mayor al menor, pero cuando veo abajo la segunda consulta de expediente esa "/" me complica mucho porque el resultado queda algo así en orden descendente:

```
Tipo: expediente Número: 997/1958

Tipo: expediente Número: 99/2000

Tipo: expediente Número: 98/2000

Tipo: expediente Número: 977/1958

Tipo: expediente Número: 97/2000
```

El problema es que después de la barra ese dato es una año y lo estoy viendo en cualquier orden, a parte que por ejemplo 98/... no es mayor que 977/...

Es un dolor de cabeza estos datos, intenté ordenarlos por el campo de fecha pero es varchar y escribieron todo en formatos diferentes, muchas gracias y ojalá alguien pueda darme una idea de como arreglar este desastre, gracias!!

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer uso de `SUBSTR()` combinado con `LOCATE()` para resolverlo separando ambos datos

Comment: Gracias, fue exactamente lo que hice, así después le puede pedir a mysql que ordene primero por uno y dentro después por el otro, quedó perfecto:

221/2001
220/2001
219/2001
219/2001
218/2001
217/2001
216/2001
215/2001
214/2001
214/2001

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero algo similar a:

```
SELECT *,
  CAST(SUBSTR(
      expediente,1,LOCATE('/',expediente)-1
    ) AS int) n,
  CAST(SUBSTR(
      expediente,LOCATE('/',expediente)+1
    ) AS int) ejercicio
  FROM expedientes
  ORDER BY ejercicio,n;
```

Partiendo del dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE expedientes(
  id_expediente int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  expediente varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO expedientes (expediente) VALUES
('997/1958'),
('99/2000'),
('98/2000'),
('977/1958'),
('97/2000');
```

Con el que obtendrás el resultado:

```
+---------------+------------+------+-----------+
| id_expediente | expediente | n    | ejercicio |
+---------------+------------+------+-----------+
|             4 | 977/1958   |  977 |      1958 |
|             1 | 997/1958   |  997 |      1958 |
|             5 | 97/2000    |   97 |      2000 |
|             3 | 98/2000    |   98 |      2000 |
|             2 | 99/2000    |   99 |      2000 |
+---------------+------------+------+-----------+
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios